# Pasar texto capturado en un TextField a una Jtable por medio de un button

Tags: java, jframe, jtable, jtextfield

estoy haciendo un proyecto de mi escuela con únicamente Jframes, hice una tienda de ropa use 3 Jframes uno con un menu otro con los productos de hombres y otro con el carrito de compras, entonces en el de productos de hombres el usuario elije la ropa que quiera y tiene ComboBox donde el elije el color la talla y cantidad y esos datos que elije el usuario los manda a unos TexField que estan en el Jframe carrito, lo que quiero es que el botón que dice "Agregar el producto al carrito" tome los datos que ya estan en los TextField y los mande a la Jtable ordenados como van, no use ninguna Base de datos unicamente ComboBox y textfield con la instruccion .getSelectedItem() para pasarlos a los texfield del jframe carrito.
espero me puedan ayudar gracias
[este es el jframe con los comboBox de donde se mandan los datos seleccionados a los TexField de el jframe carrito](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XbldK.png)

[image: Este es el jframe Carrito donde quiero que el boton "Agregar el Producto al carrito" tome los datos de los TextField y los mande a la Jtable]

Answer (score 0):

Primero tienes que crear un array de objetos y le pasas los valores de los TextField en el orden que quieras que se muestre, y luego le pasas el array al TableModel que utilizas con tu JTable.

Sería algo como esto:

```
     Object [] objecto = new Object[5];
     objecto[0] = TextField1.getText();
     objecto[1] = TextField2.getText(); 
     objecto[2] = TextField3.getText(); 
     objecto[3] = TextField4.getText(); 
     objecto[4] = TextField5.getText();

     modelo.addRow(objecto);
```